# PHP show if with different categories array or variable?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Having some problems here, I think I am just overlooking something really simple...

I have a CMS that have multiple categories.

How do I create a variable or array that has the included categories groups that I want to use in my SHOW IF STATEMENT ??

So for example:

```
<?php  

        $catsrow = array(
    'cat_1' => '41','46','62', 
    'cat_2' => '41','45','63',
    'cat_3' => '41','43','65'

);

?>




<?php if 

    (catsrow[0] || catsrow[1] || catsrow[2]) == ($row_DetailRS1['category']) 

{ echo 'do work' } 

    else {  ?>
```

Thanks in advance!!

I guess what I am asking is, how do I compare an array with multiple groups inside. I need to compare different grouped categories..

Like `$catsArray = ARRAY(cat_1 => '2,3,4' , cat_2 => '5,6,7' , cat_3 => '8,9,10')`

```
if $row['cat_from_page'] == $catsArray (any of the groups) then SHOW THIS { }
```

????

Comment: You want an Array to store all the categories you got and you want to show something different depending on the categorie ?

Comment: I have different category groups that I need to group into one variable...

Comment: What is the value expected for this: $row_DetailRS1['category']

Comment: It is getting the value of the category of the certain STORY that is showing!

Answer (score 0):

you may need to explode the parts of the array

Kinda like `$parts = explode(',' , $cat);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

but you will need to implode the whole thing into one array

Like `implode (',', $parts);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

My Best guess at what you're trying to do:

```
$categories = array(
        'cat_1' => array(
            '41','46','62'
        ), 
        'cat_2' => array(
            '41','45','63'
        ),
        'cat_3' => array(
            '41','43','65'
        )
);

$row_DetailRS1['category'] = '41';

foreach($categories as $category => $items) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        if($row_DetailRS1['category'] == $item) {
            echo "Item: ".$item." found in Category: ".$category."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $row_DetailRS1['cateogry'] is what I am comparing the $variable array with.  

I need to have ONE variable that has multiple cats, like you have, cat_1, cat_2, cat_3.. but I need to just have it so I can compare them all,.. sort of like $row_DetailRS1['cateogry'] = $cat_1 OR $cat_2 OR $cat_3.....

Comment: can you give me the exact data structure of $row_DetailRS1['category'] it is an array? a string of 41,46,62 ?